# TS: convert `DateConstructor => Date` and `typeof MyClass => MyClass`

Tags: typescript

How to convert `DateConstructor` type to `Date`?
And how to convert `typeof MyClass` to `MyClass`?

The code:   [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeARMAXAptNAPdA7AJjMutAN7QoD2AcgJbBoDKKATrbgObQAUAlGdBZoUAVxa5oEEQAc0LAHRVmbTn2gBfDQChglXBBSSA1rWkB5AEYArNMBQAVeLJgBeaAG1iaADTQASmgcAKJY0r4IXgC60AD0MdAAZpQs0CIQGJDQAFKMWloxAFTQ0iyUFiBoALbQABZyGAUxWihOGIwm0o7O0G4tspQJxqaWNnZdaBDuuCKVFnKR%20fHtpuOuFK0DcEioGAA%200F4AwnoGLCJ2ydD7AcGhx-qs51QseYXQ%20BO0LGDlGHM1YAAbrRLo1mq1oMtOq0IIhPt9fj0Djsrv5AiFpKiIjsgA)

```js
class MyDate extends Date { toNiceString () { return super.toString() } }
const skipObjectTypes = [Date, RegExp, MyDate] // for use as JS

/* problem here */
type SkipTypes = typeof skipObjectTypes[number]
// SkipTypes = typeof MyDate | DateConstructor | RegExpConstructor

/* desirable behavior */
type SkipTypesDesirable = Date | RegExp | MyDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[Date, RegExp, MyDate]` will contain an array of classes, so `typeof skipObjectTypes[number]` will give you a union of those classes.

If you want the instance type, you can use the `InstanceType` conditional type:

```
class MyDate extends Date { toNiceString () { return super.toString() } }
const skipObjectTypes = [Date, RegExp, MyDate] // for use as JS

/* problem here */
type SkipTypes = InstanceType<typeof skipObjectTypes[number]>
// SkipTypes = typeof MyDate | DateConstructor | RegExpConstructor
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeARMAXAptNAPdA7AJjMutAN7QoD2AcgJbBoDKKATrbgObQAUAlGdBZoUAVxa5oEEQAc0LAHRVmbTn2gBfDQChglXBBSSA1rWkB5AEYArNMBQAVeLJgBeaAG1iaADTQASmgcAKJY0r4IXgC60AD0MdAAZpQs0CIQGJDQAFKMWloxAFTQ0iyUFiBoALbQABZyGAUxWihOGIwm0o7O0G4AkvooYLgMXWgAPC2ylAnGppY2dqMQ7rgilRZykQB8+fHtpks9FK3TcEioGAA+0F4AwnoGLCJ2ydDXAcGh9wNPLyxaQA)

Answer (score 0):

Found two ways to solve this:   [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeARMAXAptNAPdA7AJjMutAN7QoD2AcgJbBoDKKATrbgObQAUAlGdBZoUAVxa5oEEQAc0LAHRVmbTn2gBfDQChglXBBSSA1rWkB5AEYArNMBQAVeLJgBeaAG1iaADTQASmgcAKJY0r4IXgC60AD0MdAAZpQs0CIQGJDQAFKMWloxAFTQ0iyUFiBoALbQABZyGAUxWihOGIwm0o7O0G4tspQJxqaWNnZdaBDuuCKVFnKR%20fHtpuOuFK0DcEioGAA%200F4AwnoGLCJ2ydD7AcGhx-qs51QseYWSlCAiKLR6tfXQjWarWgy06rQgsGENUo%20AAjD1oABJB5gXAMcYAHj6aE2EA6I1sDnBUxmcxYkQAfEDZCCOqtIShofgAEwI7G4-HWQmrEmzebuABEJUoVGxAoWcQRNxC0iuWy8cq8QA)

```
type SkipTypesMethod1 = InstanceType<typeof skipObjectTypes[number]>
type SkipTypesMethod2 = typeof skipObjectTypes[number]["prototype"]
```

Thanks to [@Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/) for the first way.